When running Ci in Gitlab, the current jobs are lost immediately
I am a beginner and faced with the following problem:
When a commit is pushed and the CI pipeline is started, the current work is disrupted, instead of queuing up.
I think the problem is in the configuration of gitlab.yml
I still don't understand how to adjust it so that everything works correctly and jobs get in line
